# rPython using wrong python installation on Mac OSX

Tags: r, rpython

I've installed python 2.7.8 alongside the 2.7.5 which comes with OSX 10.9.4.

Now how can I point `rPython` to python 2.7.8?

### Attempt #1

I've modified the OSX `.bash_profile` as follows to point everything to the newer python installation.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/:$PATH:usr/local/bin:
```

And now when I run python from the terminal, it correctly runs the newer version

```
mba:~ tommy$ which python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin//python
```

However, `rPython`, still sees 2.7.5.

```
> library(rPython)
Loading required package: RJSONIO
> python.exec("import sys; print(sys.version)")
2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]
```

### Attempt #2

It looks like the `.bash_profile` doesn't get used by R at all... so I've tried to modify the PATH within R. But still no luck.

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
> Sys.setenv(PATH = "usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin")
> library(rPython)
Loading required package: RJSONIO
> python.exec("import sys; print(sys.version)")
2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]
```

### Attempt #3

I tried removing and re-installing the `rPython` package thinking perhaps it was using the version of Python that it found upon installation. No luck either.

### Attempt #4

I've tried installing from source to see if that does anything... no luck.

## Update

Okay so it looks like the problem isn't anything to do with rPython itself.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rPython/INSTALL

> Package rPython depends on Python (>= 2.7).
>
> It requires both Python and its headers and libraries. These can be
>   found in python and python-dev packages in Debian-like Linux
>   distributions.
>
> In systems where several Python versions coexist, the user can choose
>   the Python version to use at installation time. By default, the
>   package will be installed using the Python version given by
>
> $ python --version

When I run that in the terminal..

```
mba:src tommy$ python --version
Python 2.7.8
```

But when I run it in R...

```
> system("python --version")
Python 2.7.5
```

So the problem is simply that R doesn't use OSX's `.bash_profile`. I'll need to figure out how to change `PATH` outside of `.bash_profile`, or get R to use `.bash_profile`.

What else can I try to get `rPython` working with `2.7.8`?

Comment: Really a bad idea to replace the entire PATH. Generally one extends an existing PATH. (it is well-known that the bash-PATH variable is not the same as the one R sees.

Answer (score 5):

I setup the following commands in RStudio, hope these help.

```
> system("python --version")
Python 2.7.10

> Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("/usr/local/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"),sep=":"))

> system("python --version")
Python 2.7.11
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same problem as OP and this is the solution I found worked.

First, I added the `RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=3` to my `~/.bash_profile`.  Instead of installing `rPython` using `install.packages`, I downloaded the source from CRAN and installed from the command line using `R CMD INSTALL`.  This worked fine and detected the `python3` version I had installed on my system.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't help after install as per your instructions and I do `library(rPython)
python.exec("import sys; print(sys.path)")` it still shows up the python 2.7 versions when I've specified version 3 as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the rPython INSTALL file (sorry, perhaps I should make it more explicit). It has a section on how to install rPython using the desired Python version when several coexists. It says:

> In systems where several Python versions coexist, the user can choose
>   the Python version to use at installation time. By default, the
>   package will be installed using the Python version given by
>
> ```
> $ python --version
> ```
>
> but it is possible to select a different one if the
>   RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION environment  variable is appropriately set.
>
> For instance, if it is defined as
>
> ```
>  RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=3.2
> ```
>
> it will try to use Python 3.2 (looking for python3.2 and
>   python3.2-config in the path). If set to
>
> ```
>  RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=3
> ```
>
> it will install against the "canonical" Python version in the system within the 3.x branch.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post trying to get R to use a desired Python version and found a solution which worked for me (using Rstudio on OSX Yosemeti).

Here is the Python my terminal uses, which is the one I want R to find:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

In R, `system('which python')` produces `/usr/bin/python`. I can see that this is because `/usr/bin` is to the right of `/usr/local/bin` in `Sys.getenv('PATH')`.

I tried changing my PATH in `~/.Renviron` or `~/.Rprofile` but it wasn't fixing the problem. This is because there was another `Rprofile` file running right before kernel startup completed.

To find all the `Rprofile` files on my system, I ran these commands:

```
cd /usr
sudo find . -name "*Rprofile*" -print
```

One of the files -- `R_HOME/library/base/R/Rprofile` -- contained some code which said it dealt with PATH conflicts on my OS. I guess it chose the wrong PATH of the possible choices. Adding the following line to the **end** of that file, showed me the correct path in Rstudio after restarting my R kernel:

```
.Internal(Sys.setenv("PATH", paste("/usr/local/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":")))
```

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me is that i specify the lib and version in install.packages, like this

```
install.packages("rPython",lib= "path_to_your_R/R/library/3.1", configure.vars= "RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=3")
```

And it indeed installed with python version which under 3.x