# rPython using wrong installation on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: python, r

I am having trouble with `rPython` that was previously described:

[rPython using wrong python installation on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383030/rpython-using-wrong-python-installation-on-mac-osx)

The solution to this question did not fix this problem for me. Has anyone fixed this issue in any way?

I am running OS X 10.10.3

My system version of python is 2.7.6

My homebrew version of python is 2.7.10

EDIT: Added session info and environment variables

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)

Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

Running under: OS X 10.10.3 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.3

Sys.getenv(x = NULL, unset = "")

__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
"0x1F5:0x0:0x0"

Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render
"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.yfnCHkfdKS/Render"

DISPLAY
":0"

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
"/Users/xxxxx/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib::/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib"

EDITOR
"vi"

GIT_ASKPASS
"rpostback-askpass"

HOME
"/Users/xxxxx"

LANG
"en_US.UTF-8"

LC_CTYPE
"en_US.UTF-8"

LN_S
"ln -s"

LOGNAME
"xxxxx"

MAKE
"make"

PAGER
"/usr/bin/less"

PATH
"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"

R_BROWSER
"/usr/bin/open"

R_BZIPCMD
"/usr/bin/bzip2"

R_DOC_DIR
"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/doc"

R_GZIPCMD
"/usr/bin/gzip"

R_HOME
"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"

R_INCLUDE_DIR
"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include"

R_LIBS_SITE
""

R_LIBS_USER
"~/Library/R/3.1/library"

R_PAPERSIZE
"a4"

R_PDFVIEWER
"/usr/bin/open"

R_PLATFORM
"x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0"

R_PRINTCMD
"lpr"

R_QPDF
"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/qpdf"

R_RD4PDF
"times,inconsolata,hyper"

R_SESSION_TMPDIR
"/var/folders/w5/2ynq5k4143l3q6l1t8ycm8sc0000gn/T//Rtmp5MHtVP"

R_SHARE_DIR
"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share"

R_SYSTEM_ABI
"osx,gcc,gxx,gfortran,?"

R_TEXI2DVICMD
"/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi"

R_UNZIPCMD
"/usr/bin/unzip"

R_ZIPCMD
"/usr/bin/zip"

RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH
"/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/resources/mathjax-23"

RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH
"/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/rpostback"

RS_SHARED_SECRET
"bffeb2cd-6de9-4569-a43c-3e5649d5b49d"

RSTUDIO
"1"

RSTUDIO_PANDOC
"/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc"

RSTUDIO_SESSION_PORT
"29965"

RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY
"xxxxx"

SED
"/usr/bin/sed"

SHELL
"/bin/bash"

SSH_AUTH_SOCK
"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.tFlHYxJ9cI/Listeners"

TAR
"/usr/bin/tar"

TMPDIR
"/var/folders/w5/2ynq5k4143l3q6l1t8ycm8sc0000gn/T/"

USER
"xxxxx"

XPC_FLAGS
"0x0"

XPC_SERVICE_NAME
"0"
```

Comment: You need to show what the environment variables are set to when R is running (and we need to see sessionInfo() output). The above information is not useful unless we see the rest of your setup.

Comment: I added the environment variables and the sessioninfo() output. I also contacted the maintainer of rPython and he is having similar trouble with Anaconda. He wrote up a recent post about it in hope that someone can help with this issue. http://www.datanalytics.com/2015/06/22/rpython-anaconda/