# can't import package with rPython

Tags: python, r, rpython

I installed `umap-learn` on `mac OS` and tried to use it in `r markdown` file using `rPython` the way it is explained here:

http://blog.schochastics.net/post/using-umap-in-r-with-rpython/#fn1

But when I run following code:

````
```{r}
umap <- function(x,n_neighbors=10,min_dist=0.1,metric="euclidean"){
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  colnames(x) <- NULL
  rPython::python.exec( c( "def umap(data,n,mdist,metric):",
              "\timport umap" ,
              "\timport numpy",
              "\tembedding = umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=n,min_dist=mdist,metric=metric).fit_transform(data)",
              "\tres = embedding.tolist()",
              "\treturn res"))

  res <- rPython::python.call( "umap", x,n_neighbors,min_dist,metric)
  do.call("rbind",res)
}

data(iris)
res <- umap(iris[,1:4])
```
````

I get the error:

> Error in python.exec(python.command) : No module named umap

So, apparently `Rstudio` does not see the `umap`. I checked that the package is installed by `conda list`:

```
umap-learn                0.2.3                    py36_0    conda-forge
```

How could I fix that?

> Update

The version of python was wrong, so I added `.Rprofile` and made it point to the right version, however, the error persisted.

```
system("python --version")
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

> Update

More detailed error (stack trace):

```
 Error in python.exec(python.command) : No module named umap
 4.stop(ret$error.desc)
 3.python.exec(python.command)
 2.rPython::python.call("umap", x, n_neighbors, min_dist, metric)
 1.umap(iris[, 1:4])
```

Comment: No, how can I verify that? And then switch if it is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that `umap` is available to the same Python used in R, which is not going to be your Anaconda installation by default.

You can check your Python with `system("python --version")` and if needed go on the `cmd` line and do `pip install umap` or `pip3 install umap` etc (to use the currently available Python; alternately you can [switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705878/rstudio-python-version-change-on-mac) the Python path to your Anaconda Python).

Comment: Just to add, the following thread helped me switch to the right python version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705878/rstudio-python-version-change-on-mac

Comment: However, `umap` can not still be found.

Comment: `pip3` is not installed probably since it is writing that `command not found`. The error is the same `No module named umap`

Comment: I ran successfully `pip install umap` but did not fix the error.

Comment: R version is `3.5.0`

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko Thank you. I see now that I'm not going to be able to replicate your situation because my Windows version is different from your macOS version. OK. Can you please run this in Python via R?  `import sys` then 
`print (sys.path)` We want to verify that it can hit the library folder.

Comment: It is definitely trying to use `Python 2.7`, not the right one. So, in `Rstudio` the `python` version is correct, but `rPython` is switching the version.

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko OK that's what it sounded like. So we gotta get the PYTHONPATH changed then (or put the library in 2.7). So the linked solution didn't work? I can help you try more but I'm not on macOS so I cant test it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387695/add-to-python-path-mac-os-x

Comment: The linked solution worked. Output of `system("python --version")` is correct

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko Oh I see, so the python executable is right but the sys path for modules is wrong. OK lets just update that part.